# How to make a destructible tilemap? unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently making a terraria-like game. And I'm at the stage of adding and breaking blocks. How can I check for collision and make the block that the bullet touched disappear?

Here is my current tilemap script :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class DestructibleTiles01 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Tilemap destructibleTilemap;

    private void Start()
    {
        destructibleTilemap = GetComponent<Tilemap>();
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("TerraFormingBullet"))
        {
            Vector3 hitPos = Vector3.zero;
            foreach(ContactPoint2D hit in collision.contacts)
            {
                hitPos.x = hit.point.x - 0.01f * hit.normal.x;
                hitPos.y = hit.point.y - 0.01f * hit.normal.y;
                destructibleTilemap.SetTile(destructibleTilemap.WorldToCell(hitPos), null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for some odd reason, nothing happens when my projectile collides with the tilemap. I followed a tutorial on how to make this destructible tilemap but because I'm new to C#, I don't fully understand everything in this script and thus, I can't debug this code. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you given the tilemap the `"TerraFormingBullet"`  tag

Comment: ////////////yes